# How to solve collective.js.jqueryui versioning for both Plone 4.2 and 4.3

Tags: plone

I have an addon which I want to update to be compatible with Plone4.3, but which should remain functional when Plone4.2 users do an upgrade.

The [readme](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.js.jqueryui/1.10.3) says this:

> For Plone 3 you need version 1.7.x of this package
>   Plone < 4.3 Use version < 1.9

How can I configure this kind of version-specific dependency in setup.py?

Comment: Are you asking, how to ensure that Plone-4.2.x-products will work with Plone-4.3.x, too? Because the readme you point to, refers to Plone-3-compatibilty not P4...

Comment: It refers to Plone 3, Plone 4 < 4.3, and Plone 4 >= 4.3.  Yes, though, that is precisely what's at stake here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's c.js.jqueryui which should pin the Plone-versions in their tag-releases, IMHO.
So you should contact the authors probably.
To be consequent, you should add 'Products.CMFPlone' as a dependency, too, but I don't know what is best practice here.

Anyway, to answer your question, here is a possibilty to distinct, whether we have a Plone-3 or not:

In your `setup.py` add at the top

```
import glob

# BBB: Append Plone-3-specific version-pinnings
# to `install_requires`, in case third-party-eggs
# do not specify their requirement-versions.
# Assumes, Plone-eggs are in the same directory
# as this egg, which is given, if fetched of pypi.
# Otherwise assumes, you know how to tweak
# buildout and pin versions yourself.

# Collect P3-eggs in eggs-directory:
plone3_eggs = glob.glob('../Products.CMFPlone-3*')

# Found something?
if len(plone3_eggs) > 0:

    # Expects `install_requires=[ ... ] + plone3_requires,`
    # in setup-method below, to take effect:
    plone3_requires = [
    'collective.js.jqueryui<=1.7',
    # Add more P3-pins here.
    ]
```

And `install_requires` in the setup-method, gets this:

```
      install_requires= [
    'setuptools',
    'collective.js.jqueryui',
    ] + plone3_requires,
```

Comment: @Campbell: Might be also of interest for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036181/provide-a-complex-condition-in-install-requires-python-setuptoolss-setup-py